# Return any string of n contiguous numbers from a column

Tags: r, database, data-manipulation

Suppose I have a dataset:

Have:

```
example1 example2
11-2001-6 st3829s
11-2001-6 s8290s
11-201-6 sts39
```

Want:

```
example1 example2
2001 3829
2001 8290
NA NA
```

I want to output the numbers that are 4 contiguous numbers or n numbers (specify length).
If no group of 4 numbers occurs together return NA.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `str_extract` and `mutate_all`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
mutate_all(df,  ~str_extract(., pattern= "\\d{4}"))
 example1 example2
1     2001     3829
2     2001     8290
3     <NA>     <NA>
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply this pattern lookup to one variable only?

Comment: Yes , it is! try `mutate(df, example1 = str_extract(example1, pattern= "\\d{4}"))` this is applied only to `example1`

Answer (score -1):

First Things we are talking about regular expression.
Second i will solve this using PHP language and you should find the solution for your program language

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/', '11-2001-6 st3829s', $output_array);
```

this will output

```
array(1
0   =>  array(2
0   =>  2001
1   =>  3829
)
)
```

but if you path

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/', '11-201-6 sts39', $output_array);
```

this will output

```
array(1
0   =>  array()
)
```

so you have check the output and if it empty array you have return NA

Comment: Hi @abdul rahman souda this is an R specific question, even if you answer your question, you used another language